# Duplicate but totally its not

Tags: discussion

I'm just confused, 
How do we tag a page as 100% Duplicate from the other page like:

This:[Parent Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577729/how-to-add-new-sheet-with-data-come-from-db-to-existing-excel-file-when-download)

Become duplicate to this: [Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951599/getting-current-directory-in-net-web-application)

Comment: The person that closed it is a regular here, but just a glance at it (and me not knowing much of C#) - looks like an accurate dupe to me, at least.

Comment: Because they use the "~\\path\\file.xlxs" format to get the full path of their file which doesn't work that way, Excel (or the WIN32 Api really) don't know how to expand that `~` to  full path. The duplicate explains how to do that in a web scenario. I could have closed it as well as No MCVE as the title and problem have nothing to do with each other. I normally ignore images of error message but this one was too obvious.

Comment: The error is occurring because they're attempting to open a file via the server mapping. The duplicate target explains how to translate that into a physical file path.

Comment: Also worth noting that the rest of their code look decent, so I don't expect them to run into other problems once they fixed this main issue.

Comment: Thanks to all but how about the Question `How to add new sheet with data come from database.......`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note the title of the "Duplicate" closure banner:

> **This question already has an answer here:**

A question doesn't have to be a 100% match to be closed as duplicate.
As long as it's the same problem, that can be answered with the same answer, it can (and should) be closed.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, in that situation i think we need to ask the OP first the real problem like `Any idea how I can achieve to do this to get the file with adding new sheets to existing file`. I think he is looking also some help to this`adding new sheets`.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question, though.

Comment: yeah it's not too clear according to the image posted, He need the right project path but the title it doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

I've addressed their error message, not their title or other code as I didn't see any blatant issues in that.

Their mistake with expecting that the "~" would expand to a full path also when given to Excel is an understandable oversight and the duplicate target has a decent question and concise accepted answer that addresses the current blocking issue for the OP.

The duplicate is fine.